# Cognos query calculation - how to obtain a null/blank value?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a query calculation that should throw me either a value (if conditions are met) or a blank/null value.

The code is in the following form:

`if([attribute] > 3) 
then ('value') 
else ('')`

At the moment the only way I could find to obtain the result is the use of '' (i.e. an empty character string), but this a value as well, so when I subsequently count the number of distinct values in another query I struggle to get the correct number (the empty string should be removed from the count, if found).

I can get the result with the following code:

`if (attribute='') in ([first_query].[attribute])) 
then (count(distinct(attribute)-1) 
else (count(distinct(attribute))`

How to avoid the double calculation in all later queries involving the count of `attribute`?

Answer (score 2):

I use this Cognos function:

```
nullif(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this can be managed using the `case when` function:

`case 
when ([attribute] > 3) 
then ('value') 
end`

The difference is that `case when` doesn't need to have all the possible options for Handling data, and if it founds a case that is not in the list it just returns a blank cell.

Perfect for what I needed (and not as well documented on the web as the opposite case, i.e. dealing with null cases that should be zero).

Comment: You can also just use null as in: CASE WHEN [attribute] > 3 THEN 'value' ELSE null END. The same can be done using an IF.

Comment: @Johnsonium I tried that way but my cognos threw out an error, it didn't like the null as a constant... Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: That's odd. I use null all the time in that way. I do know that Cognos is sometimes excessively picky about the exact syntax of expressions. For instance, requiring an ELSE clause in an IF within a filter expression.